# Organisation-wide default header and footer for Ofiice365 Documents

Tags: office365

I'm one of the administrators. We are struggling to find out how to enforce or set a default header or theme for each document that is created.

For example, if one of our users creates a new Word, or Excel file, our company logo is across the top.

It sounds like something that we should easily be able to do but we have not been able to figure it out for the past few days

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a green hand in this forum, I could not make a comment. I have found an article: [Distributing macros to other users](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DistributeMacros.htm) that I hope it could be helpful. I suggest you create a new template which has your company logo or the header you want, and then you could distribute the template via a login script when users login. For more information you may refer to this article.

Comment: Hi @Emily Hua, this seems like a reasonable answer, but by itself, there isn't much usable information. Could you copy the essential parts of that document you're linking to your answer? Links are ephemeral and could change anytime, or the linked documents may disappear.